# WordPress HTML5 Gallery Support - Convert HTML4 -> HTML5

Tags: theme-development, gallery, html5, add-theme-support

As of WordPress 3.9, [WordPress generates HTML5 Galleries](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/15/html5-galleries-captions-in-wordpress-3-9/) if   HTML5 is supported in the theme:

`add_theme_support( 'html5' );`

Originally in my theme development I did not declare HTML5 support and I've already published a few galleries which are using the old `DT` / `DL` HTML. Now I have declared HTML5 theme support as shown above, but WordPress won't regenerate my gallery even after saving the page or publishing a new gallery.

How do I "trick" WordPress or have WordPress start generating HTML5 galleries after my theme has been activate / activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'gallery', 'caption' ) );
```

And don't forget to declare the HTML5 DOCTYPE at the very beginning of `header.php` with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I guess I didn't read that WP 3.9 Gallery Article all the way through: `"For forward compatibility reasons, the second argument with the specific parts can’t be omitted when registering support. Otherwise a theme would automatically declare its support for HTML5 features that might be added in the future, possibly breaking its visually because of it."` -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By Using

```
add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
```

Support for the gallery and caption

Example

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array('gallery', 'caption' ) );
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support